# Upload repository to GitLab from SFTP

Tags: git, gitlab, cpanel, sftp

i have website on cpanel based server, and it tooks me too long to upload manually website to my server by downloading from my server and uploading manually via web ui gitlab interface

I was trying with deploy tokens or deploy keys but nothing helps, can you please advice how to fix this?

Is there some sftp username that you provide so i can upload the files over there when i make changes so you have ability to push those changes to main branch.

I hope i was clear, thanks.

Comment: You want to sync your SFTP server TO GitLab? Not the other way around? I'm not sure how you'd set that up in cpanel, but you should be able to simply use either `git` or the GitLab API. There is no SFTP endpoint for GitLab repositories, it just doesn't work that way. As far as the issues you're having, you'll have to share with us some details on  how you're trying to configure this and what problems you're running into, like error messages.

Comment: Scenario is :
1. i have cPanel server with my website
2. my editors only know to upload files to cpanel file manager
3. i have to push everytime the changes they do to gitlab repro (specific branch)